# Does siphoning through a garden hose to a basement make sense?

Tags: water, drainage

I'd like to drain some rainwater sitting on an in-ground pool cover. I siphoned the first few inches quite easily with one end at the street level—which, luckily, is a little lower than both the front- and the back- yards—and the other in the pool.

That still left me with a few more inches. Had I had a rain chute right in front of the house, I would have just dangled the garden hose in a little and continued the drainage. That makes me wonder. What is to stop me from simply taking the garden hose through a window and down to the sink in the basement? I'd keep in eye that there are no microscopic holes in the hose, and I'd be sitting next to the sink in the basement for the 2-3 hours that the task will take to make sure I don't end up with a flooding.

All in all it's an entirely passive method, but my gut feeling tells me it's irrational to take a garden hose, even one carrying water passively, into the house. What am I missing?

Comment: I run a hose out of the house every week or two in the winter to fill the hot tub. I wouldn't think twice about this?  What is the issue?

Comment: Rather than sitting next to it, secure it at both ends and get on with something else. If you're relying on watching it and have to leave it, that's when things will go wrong (e.g. rushing for the doorbell)

Comment: Someone pays to process water than goes down a drain.  Consider draining to a backyard instead.

Answer (score 1):

It may not seem intuitive to do this, but *not to* would be irrational. Temporally secure the hose to something so that it can't fall out of the sink, and go to lunch. Sticking it as far as it will go into a (known working) floor drain would be even better.

I've been doing some work in my basement lately. Step one of every morning, is hosing off the 100 years of brick dust so I can tuck point it. *"A little water never hurt anything."*

Answer (score 1):

You really are not supposed to divert rain/stormwater into the municipal sewers. It costs the city a lot of money to treat that water.

The right tool for this job is a pool cover pump. You can then pump the water wherever you want (a dry well, storm drain, or even just into your yard if the quantity is not too great).